# context menu strange behaviourin SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, menu

Since last week we can't open the context menu of an item anymore in SharePoint 2007 when using Internet Explorer. It doesn't load below the dropdown-arrow, but at the bottom of the screen and you can't click on any of the options:

[image]
Internet Explorer version is 11.316.17763.0 and Compatibility View is enabled (disabling it doesn't help).
In Chrome the context menu loads fine, but recommending Chrome is not an option because of other compatibility issues between SP2017 and Chrome.

Any ideas how this can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably related to some update that was placed on the server and client in the past week. As you are in SP2007 you are out of support so only thing you could do (but I would not recommend it) is to review updates that were placed, remove one by one to determine the culprit and then decide can you live without that update.

In any case I would recommend to upgrade your Sharepoint installation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I will check if some updates were installed on the server. And we already have a new SharePoint online environment in place, but the old 2007 environment is being phased out. But it is still being used for quite some long-running projects.

Comment: If it is security update that caused the issue you might be able to open a ticket with MS.

Comment: No updates installed on the server since 2017, so that can't be the reason. We also tried it in an old IE9 browser and there it still works fine. So probably it has to do with a recent IE11-update or Windows 10 update. I don't know exactly how to deal with this.

Comment: you don't need to it is case for desktop support ;) but process in identification needs to be the same uninstall recent updates until you find the culprit and then assess the risks.